# How to declare a variable of type Type in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

i need to store a type variable to later on instanciate it dynamically. now i cant find how to declare a variable of type Type and searching for this is extra difficult because of the language name. but from what i found it indicates that there is nothing for that and any should be used but i would prefer not to.

simple example:

```
class Foo {}

function test(bar: ???|any) {...}

test(Foo); // just the type not an instance
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Foo` is *not* passed as a type¹. When you do `test(Foo)` you do pass a constructor function (thats a value not a type), and that constructor function returns objects of type `Foo` (it both refers to a value and a type here). The correct type would be the type of the `Foo` variable and not the type `Foo` (yes, thats a bit confusing²):

```
  function test(bar: typeof Foo) { /*...*/ }
```

Or more explicitly, you could also directly type it as a Foo constructor:

```
   function test(bar: { new(): Foo; }) { /*...*/ }
```

---

¹Note: You can't pass types, as they don't exist by the time the code is run, types only exists at compile time, not runtime.

---

²An example that might make it more clear:

```
  //            v the type  v the value
  const value: Foo = new Foo();
```

Comment: i see thanks. i think `{ new(): Foo; }` is more clear to understand and will go with that. even after quite some time using js/ts its still a challenge as someone who usually uses static typed, compiled, languages. webasm can't come soon enough

Comment: It has its benefits ... generics in typescript are really elegant, and they allow you to fine tune how a value can and cannot be used. Yes, sometimes it is complicated though